# Problema con where en LinqToExcel

Tags: c#, linq

Estoy usando **LinqToExcel** para leer los datos de un libro, y funciona bien, ahora lo que intento es meterle una clausula `where`, para obtener datos mas limpios.

Tengo esto:

```
var resultado = (from row in book.Worksheet(NombreSheet)                           
                         let item = new Clases.Comprobante.Comprobante
{
    //Asignaciones por aqui y por alla
}
select item).ToList();
```

Lo dicho, esto funciona bien, y me trae todos los datos que están en la hoja de **excel** y arma un objeto Comprobante. La idea es meterle una clausula `where` para que los datos que me arroje ya estén limpios, y no limpiarlos después.

Dentro de esa hoja, tengo varias columnas, una de ellas se llama **ACTIVO**, con un valor **1** o **0**, dependiendo el caso, lo que quiero intento hacer es esto:

```
var resultado = (from row in book.Worksheet(NombreSheet)
                             where row["ACTIVO"].Cast<string>() == "1"                     
                             let item = new Clases.Comprobante.Comprobante
{
     //Asignaciones por aqui y por alla
}
select item).ToList();
```

Que unicamente me cree el objeto si la columna ACTIVO de la linea, contiene un 1.

Si lo intento así, me da esta excepción:

> "No coinciden los tipos de datos en la expresión de criterios."

aparte de un error en el debug y algo del COM....

Alguna idea?

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

`.Cast<string>()` lo que hace es tratar que está en `row["ACTIVO"]` como un IEnumerable y tratará de convertir cada `char` a `string`, lo que probablemente debes hacer es simplemente un cast normal `(string)row["ACTIVO"]` y `"1"` como string.

```
var resultado = (from row in book.Worksheet(NombreSheet)
                             where (string)row["ACTIVO"] == "1"                     
                             let item = new Clases.Comprobante.Comprobante
{
     //Asignaciones por aqui y por alla
}
select item).ToList();
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, sigue el mismo problema, he trabajado muy poco con linq, dentro de el mismo no me deja incluir un if para comprar esa columna y no alimentar el objeto. Saludos

Comment: No estoy seguro si la columna la devuelve como `string` o como `int`. Puedes intentar castear a `int` y comprararlo contra `1` y ya no contra `"1"`?

Comment: ¿Sigue el mismo problema? ¿Te da el mismo error?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con el siguiente código:

```
var resultado = book.Worksheet(NombreSheet.finsAll(Obj => (string)obj["ACTIVO"] == "1");
```